# ¿Por qué 'recorder' no almacena los datos en el archivo?

Tags: python, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy iniciando con la creación de modelos en **Openseespy**, y necesito guardar la información mediante el comando **recorder**, pero la información no se guarda en el archivo creado, ya revisé la documentación de **Openssespy**, pero no encontré el error, y ya busqué ejemplos del tema, pero no aparece nada aún. Si alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo de ante mano se lo agradezco.

Aquí el código:

```
from openseespy.opensees import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

wipe()

model('basic','-ndm',2,'-ndf',2)

node(1, 0.0, 0.0)
node(2, 144.0, 0.0)
node(3, 168.0, 0.0)
node(4, 72.0, 96.0)


fix(1, 1, 1)
fix(2, 1, 1)
fix(3, 1, 1)

uniaxialMaterial('Elastic', 1, 3000)

element("Truss", 1, 1, 4, 10.0, 1)
element("Truss", 2, 2, 4, 5.0, 1)
element("Truss", 3, 3, 4, 5.0, 1)

timeSeries("Linear", 1)

pattern("Plain", 1, 1)

load(4, 100.0, -50.0)

system("BandSPD")

numberer("RCM")

constraints("Plain")

integrator("LoadControl", 1.0)

algorithm("Linear")

analysis("Static")

example = open('example.out','a+')

ele1Global = open('ele1Global.out','a+')

recorder('Node', '-file', example, '-time','-node',4,'-dof', 1, 2, 'disp')

recorder('Element', '-file', ele1Global, '-time', '-ele',1,2,3, 'force')

analyze(1)

print('node 4 displacement:', nodeDisp(4))
printModel('-node')
printModel('-ele')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la [documentación](https://openseespydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/elementRecorder.html?highlight=recorder#element-recorder-command), lo que espera el argumento `-file` es el nombre del archivo en forma de cadena:

> **filename (`str`)**
>   name of file to which output is sent. file output is either in xml format ('-xml' option), textual ('-file' option) or binary ('-binary' option) which must pre-exist.

Deberías hacer por tanto algo como:

```
import os

push_dir = 'OutFiles'
example_file = "example.out"
ele1Global_file = "ele1Global.out"

if not os.path.exists(push_dir):
    os.makedirs(push_dir)

recorder(
    'Node', '-file', os.path.join(push_dit, example_file), '-closeOnWrite',
    '-time','-node',4,'-dof', 1, 2, 'disp'
    )
recorder(
   'Element', '-file', os.path.join(push_dit, ele1Global_file), '-closeOnWrite',
   '-time', '-ele',1,2,3, 'force'
   )
```